# Process text input through a textarea

Tags: php

i have website with text area where user pastes text which looks like this:

```
Name
Surname
Age
Mail

John
Smith
99
john@john.com
```

i want to make variables from words "John","Smith",... and then save them to database

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaboom!

```
<?php
// $string = "John\nSmith\n99\njohn@john.com";
$string = "John
Smith
99
john@john.com";

$values = explode("\n", $string);

print_r($values);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Smith
    [2] => 99
    [3] => john@john.com
)
```

Comment: could you please write whole code that makes array, for start i don't need any output, thanks

Comment: @Miso: That IS the whole code. The `print_r` is just there to show you the contents of `$values`.

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like:`list($name,$surname,$age,$mail) = split("\n",$input);`

Can't promise that will work but it is a start.

Comment: You need to use double-quotes around `\n`.

Comment: ^ Oops, bad habits strike again. Thank you

Comment: +1, this answer provides named variables rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the split() function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "your text here";
$string = str_replace("\n", " ", $string);
$string = str_replace("\r", "", $string);

$array = explode($string,' ');
```

$array will contain all words from text.

Comment: This will fail if someone has a first name like `Billy Bob` or a last name like `Van Voort`